# Returning Eigen matrices and temporaries

Tags: c++, eigen3, temporary-objects, return-value-optimization

Consider the following function `Foo`:

```
// ...

Eigen::Vector3d Foo() {
    Eigen::Vector3d res;
    // ...
    return res;
}

int main () {
    Eigen::VectorXd foo = Foo();    // (1)
    return 0;
}
```

The line `(1)` should not create any temporaries due to return value optimization. But consider the following case:

```
// ...

int main () {
    Eigen::VectorXd foo;
    // ...
    foo.head<3>() = Foo();    // (2)
    return 0;
}
```

**Does `(2)` create any temporaries? More generally, does initializing any block of a matrix as in `(2)` create any temporaries?** It would be great if this were not the case. Otherwise, I could redefine `Foo` as follows:

```
// ...

void AlternativeFoo(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector3d> res) {
    // Modify res
}

int main () {
    Eigen::VectorXd foo;
    // ...
    AlternativeFoo(foo.head<3>());    // (3)
    return 0;
}
```

**Is `(3)` the only way to achieve the above without creating temporaries?**

Comment: NRVO is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The line (1) should not create any temporaries due to return value optimization.

No, it must materialize a temporary for the return value of `Foo`.

The return type of `Foo` and the type of the variable `foo` do not match (up to cv-qualification): `Vector3d` vs `VectorXd`.

But this is a necessary condition for copy elision to be allowed.
If that is not the case, the constructor used will be neither a copy nor a move constructor in the first place.

So elision doesn't happen and in the constructor that is going to be called, the return value of `Foo` is bound to a reference argument, which will cause materialization of the temporary.

> Does (2) create any temporaries? More generally, does initializing any block of a matrix as in (2) create any temporaries?

Yes, again temporaries for the `Foo` return values will be materialized, this time caused by binding to reference parameters in the `operator=`.

> Is (3) the only way to achieve the above without creating temporaries?

I would assume so, but it probably doesn't matter anyway.
Assuming `Foo` can be inlined, the distinction is likely going to become meaningless and the compiler will figure out if the operations in `Foo` can be performed directly on the storage of `foo` or not.

If `Foo` cannot be inlined, then copying the three entries of the vector is unlikely to have significant relevance against the function call. Your alternative solution would in this case force extra indirection, which may be more costly than copying a few values as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, RVO in `(1)` would only work if `foo` were exactly an `Eigen::Vector3d`, right? As to your comments about the approach `(3)`, do you really think that copying three vector entries would not be that costly compared to a function call? What if the elements are six? Nine? What you say implies that using `Eigen::Ref` is only convenient when there are _many_ entries in the vectors: is this statement really true? I would expect it to always be _at least_ as efficient as passing by copy a vector of identical dimensions!

Comment: @fdev Yes, if the types match exactly, then it works. Whether or not `(3)` is more performant will dependent on the details I guess. If the vectors are large, then it seems likely to me that `(3)` will have an advantage, but inlining and optimization make it not very obvious to me which variant is preferable at which size. I guess it needs to be benchmarked for your specific situation.

Comment: @fdev With inlining I would also expect it to be usually at least as efficient as the `(2)`. Only for the case that inlining does not happen, there might be additional cost due to the indirection necessary in `AlternativeFoo`.

Comment: I see, then compilers make it harder for me to decide which direction to take! The most reasonable approach to implement the above would be for me to use `Eigen::Ref`, but why should I do it if the compiler would make my efforts useless? The official _Eigen_ page does not mention any real drawbacks about using `Eigen::Ref` compared to standard vectors.